# Acumatica "Related Entity Description" task field doesn't calculate

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a strange issue.  I'm trying to add a task related to a lead.  I wrote the following code and it works fine and appears under the lead under activities.  However, when I browse the tasks, the "Related Entity Description" field is blank.  I looked at the code behind it and it appears related entity description should be automatically calculated from the RefNoteId in Acumatica 6.  If I manually create an item under the lead/activity then all other lead/activities update the "related entity description" properly.  Looking at the source, it appears this field is myTask.Source which is a string value and I'm not sure what it should be set to since it should be calculated automatically with the noteid.  I looked in the SQL database and all fields from a manually created task and my automatic created task including the NoteID are correct so it appears I'm missing some sort of "update" command.  Any insight what I am missing to get the "Related Entity Description" to calculate correctly?  Thanks.

```
private void followuphelper(int daysToFollowUp)
        {
            #region Event Handlers
            Contact curLead = Base.LeadCurrent.SelectSingle();
            CRTaskMaint graph = CRTaskMaint.CreateInstance<CRTaskMaint>();

            CRActivity myTask = new CRActivity();
            myTask.Subject = String.Format("FollowUp Lead");
            myTask.ClassID = 0;
            DateTime dueDate = DateTime.Now;
            myTask.StartDate = dueDate;
            myTask.EndDate = dueDate.AddDays(daysToFollowUp); //2 weeks

            myTask.RefNoteID = curLead.NoteID; 
            myTask.ContactID = curLead.ContactID; 

            CRActivity task = (CRActivity)graph.Tasks.Insert(myTask);

            Base.Actions.PressSave();
            graph.Actions.PressSave();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just verified below code and it does show up Related Entity:

```cs
public class LeadMaintPXExt : PXGraphExtension<LeadMaint>
{
    public PXAction<Contact> FollowUpTask;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "FollowUp Task")]
    [PXButton()]
    private void followUpTask()
    {
        CRTaskMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CRTaskMaint>();

        CRActivity myTask = new CRActivity();
        myTask.Subject = String.Format("FollowUp Lead Test");
        myTask.ClassID = 0;
        DateTime dueDate = DateTime.Now;
        myTask.StartDate = dueDate;
        myTask.EndDate = dueDate.AddDays(10);

        myTask.RefNoteID = Base.Lead.Current.NoteID;
        myTask.ContactID = Base.Lead.Current.ContactID;

        CRActivity task = (CRActivity)graph.Tasks.Insert(myTask);

        graph.Actions.PressSave();
    }
}
```

[image]

Related Entity Description is looking for a matching `NoteID` record in `Note` table. This record gets created on-demand, when needed. For New Lead, if you wish you continue with above code, then you need to request Note creation by calling GetNoteID for PXNoteAttribute and persist the record.

Example:

```
PXNoteAttribute.GetNoteID<Contact.noteID>(Base.Lead.Cache, Base.Lead.Current);
Base.Actions.PressSave();
```

Out-of-box Activity actions (Add Task, Add Event Etc), takes care of this internally. If you use below approach, all initialization is done internally.

```cs
public class LeadMaintPXExt : PXGraphExtension<LeadMaint>
{
    public PXAction<Contact> FollowUpTask;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "FollowUp Task")]
    [PXButton()]
    private void followUpTask()
    {
        try
        {
            //out-of-box Activities -> "New Task" Action
            Base.Actions["NewTask"].Press();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is PXRedirectRequiredException)
            {
                CRTaskMaint graph = (ex as PXRedirectRequiredException).Graph as CRTaskMaint;
                if (graph != null)
                {
                    CRActivity myTask = graph.Tasks.Current;
                    myTask.Subject = String.Format("FollowUp Lead Test");
                    myTask.ClassID = 0;
                    DateTime dueDate = DateTime.Now;
                    myTask.StartDate = dueDate;
                    myTask.EndDate = dueDate.AddDays(10);

                    CRActivity task = graph.Tasks.Update(myTask);

                    graph.Actions.PressSave();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied this function exactly and get the same result as before (no related entity).  During your test you selected an exist lead "Coudane, Benedicte".  However if you create a new lead with Firstname=test27, Lastname=test28 and save then hit the Followup Task button then it gives you the result I'm seeing (no related entity).  If I select "Coudane, Benedicte" and just copy the lead and change the firstname and lastname to create a new lead it also creates no related entity.  If I select "Coudane, Benedicte" and just hit follow up it works.  Again just not for new leads which is the strange..

Comment: It appears that some flag or other "update" function needs to take place in order to get the function to populate the Task.Source field.  Once it's "activated" then it works properly.  If you create a new lead then hit the button 3 times it will create 3 copies of the task all with no related entity .  But if you then go and change 1 of the tasks related entity to the correct one, the other 2 in the list will magically update.  The "Coudane, Benedicte" lead seems to already have this flag set so works immediately but new leads do not.